# vert.x use more than one handler

Tags: vert.x, vertx3

Is it possible to add 2 handlers for a path?

I need to load `html` contents from a folder and check `session` values when i access `/` path.

If i place `router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("webroot"));`  it will read contents from `webroot` folder.

And when i use the following code, It will execute the hanlder  code.

```
router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
            Session session = routingContext.session();         
            String name = session.get("uname");
            // some code
        });
```

But is there any way to execute both handlers when i try to access this path?

I tried

```
HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response.sendFile("webroot/index.html");
```

But it just read the `index.html` file and it doesn't read CSS.  And I couldn't find a method to read the entire directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can :)

This is your Verticle i registered two Handlers

```
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route().path("/hello").handler(new Handler0());
    router.route().path("/hello").handler(new Handler1());

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
}

class Handler0 implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

    @Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
        ctx.put("hi", "your nice");
        ctx.next(); // IMPORTANT!!
    }
}

class Handler1 implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

    @Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
        String hi = ctx.get("hi");
        if (hi.equals("your nice") {
           ctx.request().response().end(hi);
        } else {
           ctx.fail(401); 
        }
    }
}
```

The ctx.next() calls the next Handler 
for error handling use ctx.fail

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Just as the previous comment says you can register multiple handlers. The problem is that the `StaticHandler` ends the response, so the next handler won't be called by `ctx.next()`.

The solution is to register your handlers before the `StaticHandler`.